# Encrypting and decrypting PNG files fails

Tags: python, utf-8

I am writing a program that encrypts and decrypts files in a directory and it seems to work well with text files. However, when it comes to other file types such as PNG files, I get the error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 114: character 
maps to <undefined>
```

This is a small sample of the code I am using:

```
file = open("example.png", "r")
data = file.read()
file.close()
```

When following advise from the web and using "rb" instead of "r", I get this error after trying to revert it with .decode('utf-8'):

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start 
byte
```

Is there any way I can encrypt the contents of the png file as if it were text and then decrypt it later and have it still be useable? What about other file types (exe, pdf, etc.)?

Comment: ,try open as *byte mode* (actualy you arent interesting about of data )

Comment: What would be the benefit of encrypting it as if it were text? Do you mean that you want the encrypted version of the file to consist only of text characters?  If so, you could encode the encrypted data using base64 encoding: the python function is `base64.b64encode()` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode).  However, that's an **en**coding of the data after encryption: not a **de**coding of the data before encryption, which doesn't make sense for a PNG.

Comment: @dsgdfg OP talks about "using 'rb' instead of 'r'", which does indeed open the file in byte mode.

Comment: @slothrop I don't actually need to encrypt it as if it were text, I just realized such. How do I revert the "rb" format to one that works though?

Comment: @AriesNinja by using "rb" you've already got a bytes object, which is what the input to your encryption should be.  For example, if you're using PyCryptodome, then you call `encrypt` with a bytes object: the documentation points out that you *can't* use a string (https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/cipher.html#crypto-cipher-package).  So you've already got the data in the format you need it.

Comment: encrypted work with bytes not strings, X content to bytes  and encrypt, then decrypted bytes to X content. Encryption work with bytes and don't care which data  inside. Another problem lenght is 16^n , can encrypt but never get valid data back.

Comment: Thats helpful, but now the final part. Say I've finished whatever encrypting and decrypting was happening, and now I have the raw bytes from the PNG. How do I turn it back into a string format? Trying to do that using decode() gives me the "'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81" error.

Comment: @AriesNinja If you have the bytes that represent a PNG, there's not really a question of turning it "back" into a string format, since it was never a string to begin with.  You could write those decrypted bytes back into a file (opened using "wb" mode) or pass them to a library like Pillow to create an image object.

Comment: @slothrop Oh, that makes sense. "You could write those decrypted bytes back into a file..." how would I do that? Do I need to use pillow or is there a more vanilla way to do it?

Comment: @AriesNinja it can be done in a vanilla way with something like `with open("decrypted_image.png", "wb") as f: f.write(decrypted_bytes)`

Answer (score -2):

Try using cryptography (module) to encrypt and decrypt files.
[Here](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) I hope i helped

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32802881)